# Volume of solid obtained by rotating region about $x$ axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, volume

> Finding volume of solid (using shell method) obtained by revolving the region formed by $x=2\sqrt{y}\space  ,y=-x\space, y=4$ about $x$ axis is

What i try: first we will solve $y=-x $ and $y=4$, we get $x=-4$

And we will solve $x=2\sqrt{y}$ and $y=4$, we get $x=4$

[image]

So volume of solid formed by rotating the region formed by $x=2\sqrt{y},y=-x$ and $y=2$ using shell method is

$$V=2\pi\int^{0}_{-4}\bigg[4-(-x)\bigg]xdx+2\pi\int^{4}_{0}\bigg[4-\frac{x^2}{4}\bigg]xdx$$

Can anyone please tell me is i am right or wrong? If wrong Then please tell me right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct. If you want to compute this volume through the shell method, what you should compute is:$$2\pi\int_0^4y\left(2\sqrt y+y\right)\,\mathrm dy=\frac{1\,408}{15}\pi.$$Or you can use the disk method:$$\pi\int_{-4}^04^2-(-x)^2\,\mathrm dx+\pi\int_0^44^2-\left(\frac{x^2}4\right)^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1\,408}{15}\pi.$$